# Creating a base class for custom JSON objects

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to create a base class to initialize custom JSON objects.  The reason I'm doing it this way is so I don't have to copy and paste the same function (updateResultsDictionary) over and over again for each class.  An issue I'm having now has to do with the super init, I keep getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any].Type' (aka
>   'Dictionary.Type') to expected argument type '[String :
>   Any]'

This error might not even matter if I'm not creating the base class and child classes properly.  This is the base class:

```
class JSONObject : NSObject {

  init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){}


  //Function used for all child classes to update object values
  static func updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: String, completion:
    @escaping (JSONObject?) -> Void) {

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

    _ = nm.getJSONData(urlExtension: urlExtension) {data in

      guard let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONFromData(data), let

        resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as?

          [[String : Any]] else {

            completion(nil)

            return
      }

      for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
        let jsonInfo = JSONObject(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

        completion(jsonInfo)

      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a sample child class:

```
class AirBnBObject: JSONObject {

  var airbnbUS: Int
  var airbnbLocal: Int


  init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){
 super.init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]())

    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
  }

  override init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    guard let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
      let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any],
      let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int,
      let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int
      else {
        airbnbUS = 0
        airbnbLocal = 0
       return
    }

    airbnbUS = usd
    airbnbLocal = chf
  }
}
```

This is a new way of writing json objects so it might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

The line that is giving you the error is because you are attempting to pass a dictionary *type* to the superclass init rather than a dictionary *instance*.

You want:
`super.init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]())`

The () creates an empty dictionary instance.

Also, you should always call the superclass init when you override an init. Even though in this case the superclass init is empty, it is good practice since you may change the superclass init in the future.

Also, you may want to consider making `init(resultsDictionary)` a *failable* initialiser as then you can return nil to indicate that the dictionary could not be parsed rather than "empty" objects.

**UPDATE**

I strongly suggest you read (or re-read) the chapter on initialisation in the *Swift Book*, but essentially you need to initialise the subclass properties before calling the superclass initialiser and also ensure that all paths in the initialiser call the superclass initialiser.  In your second initialiser there are two paths in which the initialiser returns, so you need to either have two super initialisers or re-structure the code.

You can use:

```
class JSONObject : NSObject {

    init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){}


    //Function used for all child classes to update object values

}

class AirBnBObject: JSONObject {

    var airbnbUS: Int
    var airbnbLocal: Int


    init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){


        self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
        self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal

        super.init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]())
    }

    override init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){



        guard let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
            let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any],
            let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int,
            let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int
            else {
                airbnbUS = 0
                airbnbLocal = 0
                super.init(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)
                return
        }

        airbnbUS = usd
        airbnbLocal = chf
        super.init(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your method and now it's returning a couple of different error: Property 'self.airbnbUS' not initialized at super.init call ,  Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Comment: Have you read the chapter in the Apple Swift book on initialisation? You need to make sure you always call the superclass Initializer and that either the superclass or the subclass Initializer initialises all properties.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with super.init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]())

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your updated code?